# timestamp from database need to be formatted

Tags: java

I am getting the time stamp from the database table in this format `03.03.03 14:29:34.000 (yy.mm.dd HH24:MI:SS)`

as shown below now I need to convert this into this format `20130509 06:00` , please advise how to achieve the date in this format

Comment: Firstly, you should be fetching it from the database *as a date* rather than in a particular text format. Then, there are *lots* of questions on Stack Overflow about formatting dates and times in Java. What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: What is the type of your time stamp?

Comment: pleae let me know the format for date to set the date in the format like 20130509 06:00

Comment: yes simple date format can format your date in this specified format

Comment: @AshishAggarwal PLS POST THE CODE THANKS

Comment: @GovindMathur no need for my code there are already lots of answer

Comment: @GovindMathur No need to shout, and SO is not a 'plz give me the codes' service.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java.text.SimpleDateFormat:

```
final String strSrcDate = "09.05.13 14:29:34.000";
final DateFormat srcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
final Date date = srcFormat.parse(strSrcDate);
final DateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm");
final String strDestDate = destFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(strSrcDate);
System.out.println(strDestDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SampleDateFormat in this way:

```
Date myDate = new Date(); // The date you post
String S = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm").format(myDate);
```

I don't understand in `20130509` if `05` is the month or the day. I've considered `05` as the month and `09` as the day